# DBD::Pg on Mac OS X - not found any way

Tags: macos, perl, cgi-bin, dbd-pg

Executing a .cgi from the command-line (as the user who has access to the db), I get

> install_driver(Pg) failed: Can't locate DBD/Pg.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
>   /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.12 
>   /Network/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.12 
>   /Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.4 /System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level 
>   /System/Library/Perl/5.12 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level 
>   /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12 .) at (eval 4) line 3.
>   Perhaps the DBD::Pg perl module hasn't been fully installed,
>   or perhaps the capitalisation of 'Pg' isn't right.

cpan -D DBD::Pg shows

> ### DBD::Pg
>
> Postgres Driver for DBI
>     T/TU/TURNSTEP/DBD-Pg-2.19.2.tar.gz
>     /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.4/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/Pg.pm
>     Installed: 2.19.2
>     CPAN:      2.19.2  up to date
>     DBD::Pg Developers (DBDPG)
>     dbd-pg@perl.org

Trying to export above path by PERL5LIB or PERLLIB has no different outcome.

The .cgi references /usr/bin/perl, which tells

> This is perl 5, version 12, subversion 4 (v5.12.4) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level
>   (with 2 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

I like to permanently set the module path to the one where DBD::Pg is installed (/opt/...). I wonder why that is not mentioned by the error outputs directory listing.

I installed DBD::Pg via cpanm.

I use Mac OS X Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You appear to have two different builds of Perl installed. The one with which you are running your script is different than the one used to run `cpan`. To install DBD::Pg with the correct Perl, use

```
perl -MCPAN -e'install DBD::Pg'
```

Replace `perl` with the path to the Perl used to run your script, if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

/opt/... indicates a "3rd party" Perl. "which perl", "which cpan" show that the 3rd party Perl is used by running capn. That's MacPort's. As I installed with cpan and cpanm, the 3rd party Perl got updated. Executing as a different user and the /usr/bin/perl shebang instruct the Mac OS X perl to be used. As I must use the shebang and the different user, I must use Mac OS X perl. Explicitly adding the module by /usr/bin/cpan DBD::Pg installs the module to the Mac OS X Perl. Now my .cgi runs. Alternatives to switch to the 3rd party Perl are changing the shebang to ".../env perl" or using aliases in the file system.